# XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://dictionary-thesaurus.com/wordlists/Nouns%285,449%29.txt

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

    <script src="jquery.js"></script>

    <script>

        $.ajax({            
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'http://dictionary-thesaurus.com/wordlists/Nouns%285,449%29.txt',
            contentType: 'text/plain',

            xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},

            headers: {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*'},

            success: function (res) {
                var words = res.responseText.split("\n");
                alert("word : " + words[2]);
            }
        });
    </script>

</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

//XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://dictionary-thesaurus.com/wordlists/Nouns%285,449%29.txt.

Comment: im getting this error when i run this html page on the localhost

Comment: You're probably running into the AJAX same-origin policy.

Comment: how to overcome that..???

Answer (score 0):

The `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header needs to be sent by the server. Sending it from the client does nothing. You will need a server-side proxy to get around the cross-domain issue.